# Removing Extra blank lines Python

Tags: python, blank-line

Hi I was making a code that turns input into a way that it seemed as if you were talking like a snake(IDK I was bored) and in the while loop it seems to print extra blank lines, how can I change my code to remove those extra lines?.
my code:

```
line = input("Line: ")
while line != "":
  line = input("Line: ")
  line = line.replace('s','sss')
  line = line.replace('S','Sss')
print(line)
```

desired output(my output is that same except after 3rd 'Line: ' I have a blank line below(SO didn't allow my blank line as valid code)):

```
Line: Say, what sound does a snake make?
    Sssay, what sssound doesss a sssnake make?
    Line: Hiss
    Hissssss
    Line:
```

Comment: and I imagine the `print` is inside the `while` right?

Comment: Yes it came out wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you meant is this:

```
line = input("Line: ")
while line:
    line = line.replace('s','sss')
    line = line.replace('S','Sss')
    print(line)
    line = input("Line: ")
```

So the `print` is *inside* the loop, and it inputs a new line at the *end* of your loop, right before the `while` condition checks if it is empty.

Comment: the `input("Line: ")` can also be directly on the `while` i guess